# VBA can't figure out why Case statement isn't workign correctly

Tags: vba, if-statement, target

I have this snippet of code in my Worksheet change event, but it's not firing like it should.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, rng6) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case IsDate(Target.Value)
        Case False
        Target.NumberFormat = "m/yyyy"
        Target = Empty
        Case True

            If Format(Target.Value, "m/yyyy") < Format(Now, "m/yyyy") Then
            MsgBox "Must not be less than" & vbLf & "current month & year !", vbExclamation, "Warning.."
            Target.Value = Format(Now, "m/yyyy")
            Else
            Target.NumberFormat = "m/yyyy"
            MsgBox Format(Target.Value, "m/yyyy") & "  " & Format(Now, "m/yyyy")
            End If

        End Select

    End If
```

The FALSE section is working properly, but when it gets to TRUE and runs through the if statement, it's returning only one or the other.

For example, I test entering in 01/2017 and it returns the first part of the IF, but when I enter in 10/2017 it returns the first part ALSO and converts it to today's M/YYYY, instead of the second part which it should because the current m/yyyy is greater than today's m/yyy.

Can anyone identify what the error is here?? I'm sure it's simple and the solution is right there/

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you do not compare dates using Format, but using DateDiff.

Comment: Why do you use the `Select Case` when a simple `if`-statement would do?

Comment: Why are you using a `Select Case` for checking all 2 possible values of a boolean value? Just do something like `If IsDate(Target.Value) ... Else ... End Select`?
@FunThomas you were faster…

Comment: I had a simple if in there before, but I re-worked it to a case to see if it made a difference,, much to my chagrin it did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the today's date with `Date`, not with `Now`. See the difference between these two:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print DateDiff("d", Date, Now)
    Debug.Print DateDiff("h", Date, Now)
    Debug.Print DateDiff("m", Date, Now)
End Sub
```

You do not need to Format a date, when you compare it. And depending on your date, you may need to do some additional adjustments: Thus try like this:

```
If DateSerial(year(target),Month(target),day(target)) < Date Then
```

When VBA/Excel compares dates, it simply compares their long numbers. The format is used only for you to know how it is displayed.

E.g., today's date is `42935`, yesterday was `42934`. You get this value by writing `?clng(Date)` in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate the use of [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/datediff-function):

```
If Not Intersect(Target, rng6) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case IsDate(Target.value)
    Case False
        Target.NumberFormat = "m/yyyy"
        Target = Empty
    Case True
        If DateDiff("m", Target.value, Now) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Must not be less than" & vbLf & "current month & year !", vbExclamation, "Warning.."
            Target.value = Format(Now, "m/yyyy")
        Else
            Target.NumberFormat = "m/yyyy"
            MsgBox Format(Target.value, "m/yyyy") & "  " & Format(Now, "m/yyyy")
        End If
    End Select
End If
```

`DateDiff("m", Target.value, Now)` will negative starting next month, 0 this month and positive before.

Edit: Note that DateDiff with "m" doesn't care if you are using `Date`or `Now` (only checks for month/year)